# Install mono and Monodevelop on a new Redhat 6.5 Workstation

Tags: linux, rhel, software-installation, mono

Does anyone know how to install Mono and MonoDevelop on a Redhat 6.5 Workstation?

I've tried a number of different things but nothing has worked. I tried using git and building with make from the mono website but it didn't build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of this comes from http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx

1) Satisfy the dependencies before compiling mono

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel \
    libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts \
    java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget
```

2) compile mono

```
cd ~
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.10.8.tar.gz
tar zxvf mono-2.10.8.tar.gz
cd mono-2.10.8
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
```

3) install mono

```
make install
```

Comment: I think this may be the first time directions on SO for a random series of linux commands actually worked on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link with a similar question:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180259/how-to-install-recent-mono-and-monodevelop/17949042?noredirect=1#comment34322834_17949042)

Quote:

> For installation instructions with apt-get or yum, see: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt

I've used this repository on Fedora 20, and I will try it on my Redhat when get round to install the os on another computer

For install from this repo on Redhat use the Centos option.

For CentOS-6 run the following as root:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:tpokorra:mono/CentOS_CentOS-6/home:tpokorra:mono.repo
yum install monodevelop-opt
```